# NO DOCUMENT RECEIVED error

Tags: docusignapi

I am receiving the error: NO DOCUMENT RECEIVED
docFile = CrystalReport1.pdf
Code is vb.net

This Code:

> ```
>       Dim requestBodyStart As String = asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             "Content-Type: application/xml" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             "Content-Disposition: form-data" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             asciCR + asciLN + _
>             xmlBody + asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             "Content-Type: application/pdf" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             "Content-Disposition: file; filename=" + docFile + " \  documentId=1" + asciCR + asciLN + _
>             asciCR + asciLN
>         Dim requestBodyEnd As String = asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY--" + asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN
> ```

Produce this Request:

> 

```
   --BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi"><status>sent</status><emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject><documents><document><documentId>1</documentId><name>\\10.1.11.100\SecureDocs\EnrollmentForms\CrystalReport1.pdf</name></document></documents><recipients><signers><signer><recipientId>1</recipientId><email>hmitchell@ata.edu</email><name>Alexandra Adams</name><tabs><signHereTabs><signHere><xPosition>100</xPosition><yPosition>100</yPosition><documentId>1</documentId><pageNumber>1</pageNumber></signHere></signHereTabs></tabs></signer></signers></recipients></envelopeDefinition>

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename=\CrystalReport1.pdf \  documentId=1

%PDF-1.7 
%���� 
1 0 obj 
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/PageMode /UseNone 
/ViewerPreferences << 
/FitWindow true 
/PageLayout /SinglePage 
/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone 
>>
(Continued Code Until:)
--BOUNDARY--
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is just a spacing issue with your post here but you have extra leading spaces before your opening boundary that shouldn't be there:

```
   --BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data
```

The next problem I see which is more likely causing your error is where you specify the `filename` in the Content-Disposition header - you have escape characters (\) but are missing the actual escape sequence, which means you are escaping the first character of the filename.

```
Content-Disposition: file; filename=\CrystalReport1.pdf \  documentId=1
```

Instead you need something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"CrystalReport1.pdf\"; documentid=1
```

Comment: Thanks Ergin  That got me past the NO DOCUMENT error now I am getting a NO RESOURCE error which I will put in a new post.